# JQuery autosuggest plugin to do the following?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for an auto suggest plugin that'll allow me to programmatically update the suggested results. I found a plugin which is almost perfect in terms of functionality.. http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin it does everything else I need it to (multiple queries, comma separation, etc.)

however, I can't seem to keep updating the list of suggested result as it doesn't appear to have that functionality. Does anyone know of a plugin similar to the one above which supports the additional functionality I require?